# Оформление select при помощи cusel в IE7

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

В форме используются селекты нестандартного вида
[image]

для их оформления используется плагин cusel.
В хроме, опере, фф, ие9, ие8 - всё отображатся как нужно, а в ие7 - не срабатывает, селекты отображаются в обычном виде [ссылка на верстку](http://web-portfolio1.narod.ru/index8/index1.html). Хотя в ие7 плагин должен работать.
Подскажите, как настроить его, чтобы и в ие7 все отображалось как нужно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас сейчас такой код:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var params = {
   changedEl: "select",
}
cuSel(params);
});
```

Уберите лишнюю запятую после `"select"` и добавьте `;` после `var params = { .. }`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var params = {
   changedEl: "select"
};
cuSel(params);
});
```

Должно работать.

Comment: да, большое спасибо, получилось!)